# border on table cell - why does it stick out by 1px?

Tags: css

Why top/bottom border on `<td>` sticks out by 1px when table's container has certain width and when table is centered ?

Picture shows the problem:

[image]

HTML:

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style=" border-top:4px solid green;border-right:4px solid green;">data 1
      <td>data 2            
  </table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
table{
  margin:10px auto;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
}
td{    
  background-color:silver;
  width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not closing the `<td>` and `<tr>`:

```
  <td style=" border-top:4px solid green;border-right:4px solid green;">data 1
  <td>data 2</td>
</tr>
```

Also, add the following CSS for:

1. Making borders even.
2. Making to use `border-box` layout.

CSS:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

td {
  background-color: silver;
  width: 100px;
  border: 4px solid silver;
}
```

> ***Note:*** You might need to tinker a bit to get the right output. We can just advice you on the right direction.

**Preview**

[image]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2vdf28xd/**

Comment: @DusanCani Did this answer help you to solve your issue or not?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was talking about different offset, the picture shows it clearly now - I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the width and height by default is calculated by the browser with

`width = width + border left + border right + padding left + padding right`

`height = height + border top + border bottom + padding top + padding bottom`

To avoid this, make sure the calculations are absolute with

```
 td {
      box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is not the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. The solution that shares praveen kumar is absolutely the same.

Comment: And my answer was first `;)`

Comment: Shouldn't be a width of the top/bottom border the same as element width ?

Comment: @Dusan Cani, you can use box-shadow with browser prefixs.           .green {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 green inset, -4px 0 0 0 green inset; 
}                                                                                                                     https://jsfiddle.net/103e9yLf/1/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was talking about different offset, the picture shows it clearly now - I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that this is a BUG in older versions of Firefox.

This behaviour does not happen in new FF version and other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following attribute for the table you might be using:

```
<table border="1">...</table>
```

Adding the border="1" attribute we can remove this 1px sticking out problem.